# Getting content of .html with using Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, request

```
function fun{    
  func_callbk = function(data)
  {
      alert(data);     
  };
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.src = 'http://somewe.com/id?callback=func_callbk';
  var h = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  h.parentNode.insertBefore(s, h);
}
```

Hi,
I have to get a json data from external url without using jQuery or PHP, just clean javascript. I have one error when im trying to run this, it's SyntaxError Unexpected Token. I have no idea what i have to do next.
Thanks for help.

Comment: In which line is the syntax error?

Comment: google pure js ajax examples - it will show you how to do it

Comment: on server, i have something like this {"key" : "value"} right, and syntax error is showing at this " : " character in server response

Comment: have you [validated](http://jsonlint.com/) the json data and checked with jQuery if it worked or not?

Comment: Please post the exact JSON data. Keep the formatting intact.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add `()` after function names:

```
function fun(){
```

I also suggest to add `var` before `func_callbk = function(data)`; otherwise, it will be a global variable which will eventually cause problems.

Comment: There is no problem, i accidentally remove () when i wrote this post.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax error is right at the start; change `function fun` to `function fun()`